# Unable to send couchdb data to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash-configuration

Hi greetings I have been trying to push data from couchdb to elasticsearch here is the code

```
input { 
couchdb_changes {
    db => "users"
    host => "localhost"
    port => "5984"
    }
}
output {
elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "playtym"          
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Please describe your problem in more details.

Comment: I have placed the above code in a "/opt/logstash/couch.conf" and running the command "$bin/logstash -f couch.conf". On running the command a pipeline is getting created but when changes happen in couchdb it is not pushing the data into elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the logstash log? so we could help you better.

Anyway, I am pasting my config that I am using to replicate my couch to elastic.

I am using couch behind nginx. The logstash is on the same server that elastic.

```
input {
  couchdb_changes {
    type => "foo"
    db => "database"
    host => "couch.example.com"
    username => "user"
    password => "pass"
    initial_sequence => 0
    secure => true
    port => 443
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "foo" {

    if "delete" in [@metadata][action] {
      mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][my_action]" => "delete" } }
    }
    else {
      mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][my_action]" => "index" } }
    }

    if [doc] {
      ruby {
        code => '
                event["doc"].each{ |k,v| event["#{k}"] = v }
                '
      }
    }
    # 6)
    if [doc] {
      mutate { remove_field => [ "[doc]" ] }
    }
    if [doc_as_upsert] {
      mutate { remove_field => [ "[doc_as_upsert]" ] }
    }
    if [@version] {
      mutate { remove_field => [ "[@version]" ] }
    }
  }
}

output {

  if [type] == "foo" {
    elasticsearch {
      index => "%{[ClassName]}" #ClassName is a doc field that I am using to organize the index and document_type
      document_type => "%{[ClassName]}"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
      action => "%{[@metadata][my_action]}"
      doc_as_upsert => "true"
    }
  }
}
```

My config was based on this:
https://github.com/gammaliu/couchdb-logstash-elasticsearch

Comment: The above code in my question is the logstash config file. I am using apache as mu server.

Comment: No log is getting dumped